# How do I get the 4bit from a 16 bit data?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bytecode, bytebuffer

I used getShort() method of byteBuffer to get me a short value, I converted it into a int and printed the binary value, which is a 16bit data, I need to access the int value of the starting 4bit from this 16bit data.

```
short bitRateShort = buf.getShort(32 + 2);
int bitRateInteger = Short.toUnsignedInt(bitRateShort);
System.out.println(bitRateInteger);//46144
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitRateInteger));// 1011010001000000
```

I need to get the integer value for the starting 4bit which in my case is 1011, How can I mask this 16 bits to get 4bit nibble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int bitRateInteger = 46144;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitRateInteger&0xF000));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((bitRateInteger&0xF000)>>12));
```

Output:

```
1011000000000000
1011
```

First, we mask the starting 4 bits with bitmask 0xF000 (binary 0b1111_0000_0000_0000). Then, we shift the resulting bits to the right by 12, to get rid of the "known" zeros at the end.

**Edit:**
As @CarlosHeuberger so kindly pointed out, you don't even need to do an `&` operation, because `>>` will truncate away all the right-side bits by default. So, do this instead:

```
int bitRateInteger = 46144;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bitRateInteger>>12));
```

Output:

```
1011
```

Comment: no need for `&` if doing `>> 12` - all other (12)  bits will be discarded anyway

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Good point, I'll revise the answer. It's been years since I last touched bit operations :P

Comment: You can omit the masking when relying on the `Short.toUnsignedInt` of the original code. However, there’s no magic behind it, it’s doing a masking operation, so I’d prefer smaller numbers, like with `(buf.getShort(32 + 2)>>12)&0xf`

Comment: @Holger That's true, but he did specify he wanted the integer value in the question. I guess your suggestion is valid w.r.t. the original, anyways. It just upcasts.

Comment: That value from the question originates from a `buf.getShort(32 + 2)` call, has its highest bit set, so it’s subject to sign extension, so you need either, the `Short.toUnsignedInt` call of the question or masking. And I’d shift first and mask afterwards, as then, the mask value is smaller and hence, generally easier to handle on the low level.

Comment: Another alternative is `buf.getChar(32 + 2)>>12`, which doesn’t need masking, but it requires the reader to understand that `char` is an unsigned short when it comes to integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Holger I'd probably prefer the `buf.getChar(32 + 2)>>12` with a comment on the line above explaining that `char` is treated as an unsigned short.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Avi answer.

Here is another approach :-

```
String first4char = Integer.toBinaryString(bitRateInteger).substring(0,4);
int intForFirst4Char = Integer.parseInt(first4char);

System.out.println(intForFirst4Char );
```

Comment: Nope, just tested: `Integer.toBinaryString(0b0011_0000_1111_0000).substring(0,4)` returns `1100`